# How to write xpath to count <P> tag between two <h2> tag?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<p>
<p>
<h2>
<p>
<ul>
<p>and two special regions:</p>
<ul>
<h2>
     <span class="editsection">
     <span id="History" class="mw-headline">History</span>
</h2>
<div class="thumb tleft">
<p>
<p>
<h3>
<p>
<div class="thumb tright">
<div class="thumb tright">
<p>
<p>
<h3>
<p>
<h3>
<div class="thumb tright">
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<p>
<h3>
<p>
<h2>
     <span class="editsection">
     <span id="Demography" class="mw-headline">Demography</span>
</h2>
<div class="thumb tright">
<p>
<div class="thumb tright">
<p>
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
<p>
<p>
<p>
```

How to count the number of `<P>` tags in between two `<h2>` tags?

Start with tag

```
<h2>
     <span class="editsection">
     <span id="History" class="mw-headline">History</span>
</h2>
```

and

```
<h2>
     <span class="editsection">
     <span id="Demography" class="mw-headline">Demography</span>
</h2>
```

the xpath should retreive 13 `<p>` tags between these two `<h2>` tag. So how to do write xpath for this?

Note: Tags `<p>` `<h2>` `<h3>` `<ul>` `<div>` are siblings.

`<p>` tags and `<h2>` tags does't contain any of the attribute.

Comment: you could have alligned the code properly

Comment: In order to be wellformed XML your tags each need to be closed. Would you mind if I edited accordingly?

Comment: This isn't XML at all -- almost all tags are unclosed. Please, edit and correct this severely malformed text.

Comment: He never said it was- it's tagged HTML, not XML.

Comment: @Flynn1179 Have a look in the edit history, the tags choosen by the thread starter were different. Plus the requested tool is Xpath so it should be Xhtml at least.

Comment: True, but my point is the OP never claimed it was XML. It's perfectly valid HTML, and it's not an uncommon misconception to believe that XPath can be used on HTML, as it is very often valid XML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
count(//p[preceding-sibling::h2[./span[@id='History']] and following-sibling::h2[./span[@id='Demography']]])
```

You can test it with the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//p[preceding-sibling::h2[./span[@id='History']] and following-sibling::h2[./span[@id='Demography']]])" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
count((//h2)[1]/following::p[count(following::h2[1] | (//h2)[2]) = 1])
```

Comment: It will count all the <p>tags. For above case it will return 18 <p> tags. We need to stop counting when //h2/span[@id='Demography'] appears.

Comment: @Vijay, Try it, before making false statements. And in your question you haven't specified exactly between which pair of `h2` elements you want the nodes to be selected. In the above expression you can easily specify in the predicate (`[]`) the necessary identifying condition. And this is correct despite the fact that what you have provided is severely malformed and not a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 1):

XPath operates on XML, not HTML. While it's possible for HTML also be well-formed XML, it certainly isn't in your case.

If you want to use XPath, you'll need to also use a tool that will load it as a valid XML DOM, or converts it to well-formed XML first. Failing that, your only realistic option is to use text processing methods to do this.